# Import bitaddress.org wallet into Bitcoin-Qt client?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bitaddress.org

I've received some bitcoins in a wallet created by bitaddress.org, and I've saved a screenshot of the webpage that has the public/private keys and the QR codes:

[image]

I've now downloaded the Bitcoin-Qt client, how do I import what I have into it as a wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Use console. Then "importprivkey *yourprivatekey*"